# Azure - Triggered by Q-message

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-queues

In our app (Azure hosted) we produce invoices, these have to be injected into an on premise accounting software. It is not possible to host an API that would be reachable from the Azure to post the invoices to.

Is it possible to create an exe that runs on-premise an that get's triggered by Azure Q-messages like WebJobs can ? Once triggered retrieve the invoice from a blob-storage-object.

Other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: This is fairly broad, with no right answer. Multiple queue types, different ways to manage your signaling, multiple ways to implement an executable. And you're also asking for general suggestions, which will get a discussion going (and StackOverflow isn't a discussion site). Unfortunately off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidMakogon what would be a good platform for this kind of questions if SO is not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One important thing I want to mention is that even `WebJobs` poll the queue at  predetermined interval (I believe the default is 30 seconds). Azure Queues don't support triggering mechanism like you think.

What you want to do is entirely possible though. What you could do is write a `Windows Service`, that essentially wakes up at a predetermined interval and checks for messages in the queue. If it finds messages, then it processes those messages otherwise go back to sleep again.

Comment: Thx. For the clarification on Azure Q's. Then the service bus might even be a better solution, but a bit tricky and complex, but No need to poll.

Comment: I haven't worked with Service Bus that much but I think it's the same deal there as well. The client needs to poll for messages. Would appreciate if you can share a link which tells otherwise.

Comment: I see this being a perfect use for SignalR